# Calling KnokcoutJS ViewModel Multiple Times from C# Without button clicks

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, knockout.js

I am Working on a SharePoint farm solution, where I have a control template that contains my User Control. I am using Knockout model to to capture all the information on the screen. Initially, when a new item is clicked, I am making the first call to My model to initialize the User Control and bind the control to the screen using ScriptManager RegisterStartupScript (All values initially are empty except dates). now when a user fills out the values, my model captures all the changes, I have a function that takes the model, converts it to XMl and saves it in a hidden text box. but I am having trouble getting to that java script function from the control template code behind. I can get it working with a button input, but I need it to work without any buttons. I tried using RegisterScripts again, but that didn't work because the page never reloaded. How will I be able to call the model again without using the button? Thanks!!

Here is a snippet of my code:

## JavaScript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    MyMasterviewModel = {
    myViewModel: new viewmodel()
    }
    ko.applyBindings(MyMasterviewModel);

   })


 var myViewModel;

 var viewmodel = function () {
 var self = this;
 self.InitializeEntity = function () {
 var initialURL = "~/_layouts/EinvoiceMVCService.asmx/InitializeModel";
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: initialURL,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function initializesuccess(msg) {
             //I get the data here
            },
            error: oninitialFail

        });
    }
    self.GetXmlFromModel = function () {
        var getxmlurl = "~/_layouts/EinvoiceMVCService.asmx/GetXml";
        var mod = ko.mapping.toJS(MyMasterviewModel.myViewModel.invoice());
        var DTO = { 'p_invoice': mod }
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: getxmlurl,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function XMLsuccess(msg) {

              //I get XML string and store it in a text box
              var xmlstring = msg.xml;
              document.getElementById("<%= txtxml.ClientID %>").value = xmlstring;
            },
            error: oninitialFail
        })

    }
```

## HTML

```
 <tr>
 <td align="right">
   Invoice Amount:
 </td>
 <td align="left">
  <div data-bind="with: myViewModel.invoice().APInvoiceHeader">
  <asp:TextBox ID="A7txtInvoiceAmount" runat="server" Style="text-align: right" 
    data-bind="numericValue: $data.InvoiceAmount">0</asp:TextBox></div>
 </td>
 <td align="right">
  Sales Tax:
 </td>
 <td align="left" style="padding-right: 10px;">
 <div data-bind="with: myViewModel.invoice().APInvoiceHeader">
 <asp:TextBox ID="AtxtSalesTax" runat="server" Style="text-align: right"
  data-bind="value: $data.Tax">0</asp:TextBox></div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <button  data-bind="click: myViewModel.GetXmlFromModel">lastest Model </button>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtxml" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

## Template control code behind (C#):

```
namespace Flexi.Entity.UI.SharePoint.EInvoice
{
    public class EInvoiceFieldControl : NoteField
    {
      protected EInvoiceMVCUserControl EInvoiceControl;

    protected override string DefaultTemplateName
    {
        get
        {
            return "EInvoiceFieldControl";
        }
    }
    public override string DisplayTemplateName
    {
        get
        {
            return DefaultTemplateName;
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        if (this.Field != null)
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
        //Here i get my user control initialized
            this.EInvoiceControl =  
            (EInvoiceMVCUserControl)TemplateContainer.FindControl("EInvoice");
        }
        if (this.ControlMode != SPControlMode.Display)
        {
            if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (this.ControlMode == SPControlMode.New)
                {
    //I go into Model and get InitializeEntity. Works fine         

 ScriptManager.  RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "initialize",              
 "MyMasterviewModel.myViewModel.initializemodel();", true);             
                    }
                }
                else
                {
            //ToDo later            

                }

            }
        }
        else 
        {
            //ToDo later
        }
    }
    public override object Value
    {
        get
        {
            EnsureChildControls();

    EInvoiceControl.getxml(); //This call is the one isn't working!
    return EInvoiceControl.getstringvalue();
        }
        set
        {
            EnsureChildControls();  
            base.Value = (String)value;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

## User Control:

```
namespace Flexi.Entity.UI.SharePoint.EInvoice
{
public partial class EInvoiceMVCUserControl : UserControl
{

public void getxml()
{
 //Here is where I want to go into myViewModel.GetXmlFromModel() 
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "lastest1", 
"MyMasterviewModel.myViewModel.GetXmlFromModel();", true);

}

   public string getstringvalue()
   {
    string val = txtxml.Text;  //It's empty here because GetXmlFromModel wasn't executed
    return val;
     }
     }
     }
```

I tried Calling registerstartupscripts from inside the control template directly, instead of going to the usercontrol, that didn't work either. I also used registerclientscripts but no luck. Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: I read your question a few times but don't really understand what you need to happen. If you don't want the button on your page what should trigger pushing stuff into the hidden field?

Comment: That's what i'm asking about. How can i trigger myViewModel.GetXmlFromModel without using a button click?

Comment: You should be able to trigger it off anything: a timer, a separate click event, something else maybe. You should just have to call myViewModel.GetXmlFromModel() whenever you want

Comment: How would I call it tho? How can I access a myViewModel.GetXmlFromModel() function from c# at that point? Register scripts doesn't work because there is no post back. So it won't run the scripts at the time I need it. It registers it and never executes it

Comment: I see, you'll have to send the model along with whatever is posting back the form. You're right, you can't access javascript objects in your codebehind. If the data's in a hidden field though you should be able to get at the hidden field.

Comment: Well the hidden field is empty initially and populated when myViewModel.getxmlfrommodel() is executed. I either need the button to auto click (which isn't working for me) or look at another click event that auto fires. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Ended Up Solving My Issue by using a Javascript function avaliable with sharepoint called Presaveaction(); as soon as you hit the sharepoint save button this function is called. And there I was able to refresh my model and get all the data on the screen,

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the values that will update in the form:

```
myViewModel.myFormValue.subscribe(function(newValue){
   if(newValue){
      myViewModel.GetXmlFromModel();
   }
});
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html